# Worksheet Code in Snowflake Web UI -> Where is it stored?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the Snowflake Web UI, you have the option to rename and/or save worksheet "code".  Where is this code stored?  Is it local to the machine, in a table on snowflake, or out in the ether of the web?

Example below:  Tab named "DEV Acct Perf CE" contains a series of SQL statements. Where are those statements stored?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are stored in S3, Azure BLOB, or Google Cloud Storage depending on where you're running Snowflake. It's stored to Snowflake-managed storage, so the only place you can access it is through the web UI. The newer UI in preview allows sharing between users. The current UI is single-user, so you'd need to copy & paste any statements.

Edit: You ***can*** see where they're stored, but I think the body of the worksheet is encrypted.

You can see where they're stored by doing this:

```
ls @~/worksheet_data/;
```

I downloaded mine and tried gunzip on the body, but that didn't work. I also tried selecting it in Snowflake using the JSON file format, but that didn't work either. I think the body field may be encrypted in addition to being compressed.

Answer (score -1):

Last I checked they were stored in your personal internal stage.

Try this:
list @~;

There should be a folder there called worksheets if I recall correctly. I never tried to open them to see what the files look like, but I did move the files from one user to another successfully when I had to recreate a user for one of my users.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-create-stage.html#user-stages